# position a label in the end of a webpage(masterpage) in a c# webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, master-pages

Im creating a website in c# asp.net,i desgined the master page,i added a link(our email id,indicating we are the developers)but,the content pages have gridviews which are not paged,so the length of the gridview varies based on the data,in all content pages using this master page.Because the length of gridview varies,when its long,the link's position seems to be in the middle of the page.I want our link to be in the bottom of the webpage.How to do this,pls help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you html footer might be more useful to you.

```
<footer>
  <p>Developed by: user2740323</p>
  <p>Contact information: <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">
  someone@example.com</a>.</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: thank you for ur reply,but,the footer is not defaultly in the bottom,(its not absolute,so,it gets positioned in the top)

Answer (score 0):

you can add a footerPlaceHolder to your masterpage like this:

```
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="FooterPlaceHolder" runat="server">
  <div>
      your info
  </div>
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Comment: thank you for ur reply,but,the footer is not defaultly in the bottom,(its not absolute,so,it gets positioned in the top)